# run 32bit elf on aarch64

Tags: arm, elf, qemu, arm64

I have installed Debian on qemu 64-bit ARM ([followed this tutorial](https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/installing-debian-on-qemus-64-bit-arm-virt-board/))

```
uname -a
```

> Linux test 4.9.0-7-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-1 (2018-07-05) aarch64 GNU/Linux

and I am trying to run 32 bit elf files on it, but some work some don't:

> bash: ./file_2: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

running file command on the file that runs, I get:

> file_1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI4 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped

and the one that does not run:

> file_2: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (ARM), statically 
>   linked, stripped

and both work on 32bit system(armv7l)

the only difference is that SYSV/ARM version.

is there any work around without recompiling the kernel?([read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648832/can-old-arm32-binary-files-be-run-on-aarch64-kernel))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the linked post suggests, this requires CONFIG_COMPAT to be enabled in the kernel. On the other hand I would be surprised if your kernel didn't have it -- the Debian 4.9.0-4 kernel I have from doing that tutorial does set CONFIG_COMPAT. You can check whether your kernel has it enabled by looking at the config file for it which will be in /boot/ in the guest. If it's missing then you need a new kernel, and nothing else will help.

However in your case you do have CONFIG_COMPAT, and some executables work. The difference between the ones that work and the ones that don't is that the working ones are EABI, and the non-working ones are OABI. OABI is an old and obsolete ABI for 32-bit Arm Linux binaries (the "O" stands for "old", and it's been a bad choice for a decade or so...) and it is not supported by the 64-bit kernel's CONFIG_COMPAT. You'll need to rebuild those binaries from source as EABI binaries if you want to run them under a 64-bit kernel.

Comment: looks like it's enabled..


cat config-4.9.0-7-arm64 | grep CONFIG_COMPAT=        

CONFIG_COMPAT=y

Comment: Thanks for checking. Also I should have read your question more carefully -- that some executables work and some don't is the clue. I've updated my answer to indicate what the difference is.