# Running 32-bit ARM binary on aarch64 not working despite CONFIG_COMPAT

Tags: linux, arm, arm64

I've got a 64-bit ARM machine that I'd like to run 32-bit ARM binaries on. As a test case I've built a small hello world for 32-bit ARM using the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` toolchain. `file` shows it as:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=61ffe5e22117a6d4c2ae37a1f4c76617d3e5facc, not stripped
```

But trying to run it produces:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# ./hello
bash: ./hello: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Based on [a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660401/run-32bit-elf-on-aarch64), I checked whether the kernel was built with the `CONFIG_COMPAT` option, and it was:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# grep CONFIG_COMPAT= /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_COMPAT=y
```

I also verified that the `armhf` architecture has been added and that the `armhf` version of the loader is present. Note that the loader itself doesn't run either:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
armhf
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# dpkg -l libc6:armhf
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version       Architecture Description
+++-==============-=============-============-=================================
ii  libc6:armhf    2.30-0ubuntu2 armhf        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# file /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.30.so 
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.30.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=dff2b536287d61ddca68f3e001e14b7c235bbf68, stripped
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.30.so
bash: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.30.so: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Other relevant system info:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 400.00
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics cpuid asimdrdm
CPU implementer : 0x43
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x1
CPU part        : 0x0af
CPU revision    : 2

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:14:25 UTC 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running out of things to try at this point. Any idea how to get the kernel to recognize these binaries and run them?

Comment: A 64-bit ARM machine is Aarch64. It looks like your binary is ARM A-32, not Aarch32. I don't believe you can run an ARM A-32 binary on Aarch64. You may want to confirm at [https://unix.stackexchange.com/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's correct based on prior questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648832/can-old-arm32-binary-files-be-run-on-aarch64-kernel – but I will check over on unix.stackexchange.com as well.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe the 32-bit EL0 is Aarch32, not ARM A-32. EL0 is Exception Level 0, and I'm fairly certain that is an Aarch feature. You should probably determine exactly what 32-bit support is provided by Linux Aarch64. I believe that question will find a home at [https://unix.stackexchange.com/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For what it is worth, I tried to setup a test environment for Aarch32 on Aarch64 several years ago. I finally had to abandon it because there was almost no practical information available. I think you probably have more information about it than I did back then.

Comment: You might also take a look at the GCC [AArch64 Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html) page. I think you need to use `-mabi=name` to get the 32-bit binaries. I believe the 32-bit binaries are Aarch32, not ARM A-32. ARM A-32 is the pre-ARMv8 32-bit instruction set. A-32 is what ARM coporporation calls ARMv5, ARMv7, etc instructions sets.

Comment: These comments are not correct, I think they represent a misunderstanding of terminology. Binaries compiled for Armv7-A (32-bit Arm) can be run on a suitable Armv8-A kernel running AArch64 (64-bit Arm, sometimes called arm64), as long as 1) the hardware itself supports 32-bit Arm, 2) the kernel supports running COMPAT tasks. A32 is used for the 32-bit execution state in Armv8-A running in Arm mode. T32 is the same, running in thumb mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it looks like the underlying problem here is not in software, unfortunately. The CPU we're using, the Cavium ThunderX2, is one of the few 64-bit ARM chips that does *not* have aarch32 support. Quoting from [WikiChip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/cavium/thunderx2):

- Only the 64-bit AArch64 execution state is support. No 32-bit AArch32 support.

So, this explains why it's not able to run 32-bit ARM binaries. I'm still fairly sure that other 64-bit ARM chips, like the Cortex-A57, are able to do this.

Update: older 32-bit ARM binaries do indeed work on aarch64 with a CPU that supports it, as shown below on an AWS ARM a1.metal instance:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-156:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | tail

processor   : 15
BogoMIPS    : 166.66
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-156:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-12-156 4.15.0-1054-aws #56-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 7 16:18:50 UTC 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-156:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
armhf
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-156:~$ file hello_hf
hello_hf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=c95f0c46dfab925db53506751d7677156e334e5c, not stripped
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-156:~$ ./hello_hf
hello, world!
```

Comment: If you have a [GCC Compile Farm](https://cfarm.tetaneutral.net/) account, then GCC117 and GCC118 are ARMv8a with Cortex A-57's. I believe they have what you need for the experiment. A compile farm account is free to FOSS developers. (Don't use GCC113-GCC116. They are early Mustang boards, and lack the A profile extensions).

Comment: And if you need it, I can provide remote SSH access to several dev-boards with Cortex A-53's. For example, a Libre Computer [LePotato](https://libre.computer/products/boards/aml-s905x-cc/). Email me at *noloader, gmail* account.

Comment: I actually just spun up one of the new AWS ARM bare metal machines, and confirmed that the older ARM binaries produced by the gnueabi and gnueabihf toolchains work there!

Answer (score 0):

This question has become more relevant as 32bit ARM chips are being phased out.
Me, I like to see old 32 bit binaries supported on new 64 bit hardware. Not so important, but convenient.
I took out my old Raspberry Pi Zero (32 bit) and Raspberry Pi 3B+ (64 bit) and for the first time installed a 64 bit OS on the 3B+ despite warnings of bugs and such and did some compiling.
No special make parameters. Just plain ordinary 32 bit compiling.
Runs fine on 32 bit and 64 bit.
Controllers and VMs will be running 32 bit architecture for many more years.
4GB memory limit is a pain yes. But for small apps its not a problem.